# Is the .git/ folder only supposed to be located in the project's root location?

Tags: git

Does git allow (i.e., is there a valid use case) a `.git/` folder inside subfolders?

Or is the `.git/` folder supposed to be only in one place and that is in the project's root location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the `.git` folder should only be at the project's root location (by design). However, the repository may be set up to use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), and this could result in subdirectories having their own `.git` folder.

Comment: True, but as a side note, recently Git has started moving the submodule `.git` *directories* elsewhere and replacing them with `.git` *files* a la `git worktree add`. (It's not clear to me exactly what the motivation for all of this was.)

Comment: i accepted this answer because of its strong position in stating about git's design. Furthermore, It also gave hints on possible use cases of the scenario that I described.

Comment: @torek I just glanced at the `git worktree` documentation. Very interesting. Maybe `git submodule`'s... peculiarities caused them to change design a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Having a unique .git directory at the root of the project is a convenience. The .git directory can be anywhere in your project (or even outside) and it can be modified by setting GIT_DIR environment variable. But if you consider having it inside a subdirectory of your project, it is quite simple to delete it unwillingly which is much harder to do if it's at the root of the project.